# How can I waterproof my mail box (post catcher)?

Tags: waterproofing, mailbox

We have a basket to catch mail which comes through an outdoor security door, like this:

[image]

There is an area behind the door which is open to the elements so the mail often gets wet. Does anyone know of a waterproof version of these mail catchers?

A previous tenant fixed a 'waterproof' cover on the top flap but it is ineffective.

Comment: A picture of the overall door and of the exposed area would be helpful.  If you can post them online somewhere and link them here we can embed them for you.

Comment: I would simply find an adequate sized generic weather proof container and adapt it to the task by cutting a rectangular opening and fastening it to the door.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo Thanks. I dont agree with your edit of my question title though - I'm waterproofing the box, not the slot.

Comment: I see - noted - you know you can edit your question to fix it, right?

Comment: Is the problem that (a) the mail's wet when it's pushed through the slot; (b) that rain comes through the slot wetting the previously dry mail; or (c) you come through the door with a wet coat and end up shaking water into your previously dry mail?  They all have different solutions (a: building a roof over the stoop; b: protecting the mail slot; c: protecting the catchment area)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could purchase a surface mounted letter box [similar to this one](http://jm-fugang.en.made-in-china.com/product/morQOETFOGHv/China-Letterbox-Mail-Box-LB-R381140V-.html). Simply cut out a hole in the back face of the letterbox near the top that fits around the existing hole in your exterior security door. Then mount the letter box onto the door in a secure manner.

[image]

The means of attachment may require a slight modification from the originally designed method intended for the unit that you purchase.This could happen for boxes that mount on keyhole screw slots like shown below that end up getting cut away by making the hole in the back of the box.

[image]

For a box of the type shown above, with the removable front panel, it would be straightforward to access the inside of the rear panel to drill suitable additional holes to mount the box. For letter boxes that do not have easy access to the inside you could resort to using some aluminum angle iron along the sides of the box to make suitable flange to allow screwing to the door.

Comment: 'Simply cut a hole' - in a metal box??? Not simple if a) you don't have the tools and b) you have never cut any metal before. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: It's pretty simple. All you need is a drill. Maybe a small file to clean it up.

Comment: This might protect the house from the rain ... but wouldn't the mail still get wet?  (and possibly even more wet, as the water won't drain away).

Answer (score 1):

Screw the mail slot shut and mount a conventional key locking weather tight mail box to the door.